# Power BI Phased Embedding Preload Event TypeError Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

### Background

I'm trying to warm start embedded report, and am having issues getting the suggested method of capturing the complete event to work.

**Official documentation states:**

> A ‘ready’ event will be fired once the preload is completed.

```
element.on('preloaded', function() {
   // do whatever you like here
});
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Phased-Embedding-API

### Issue

Following the instructions verbatim throws the following exception.

> TypeError: element.on is not a function

### My code

```
var PreloadElement;
function PreloadReport(embedUrl) {

    // Create embedding config
    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        embedUrl: embedUrl
    };

    PreloadElement = powerbi.preload(config);

    PreloadElement.on('preloaded', function () {
        console.log("scripts now preloaded into this page");          
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the object I was trying to subscribe to wasn't a JQuery object. The solution was to wrap up the element like below.

```
$(PreloadElement).on('preloaded', function() {
         console.log("scripts now preloaded into this page");
    });
```